# How to generate a random long between X and Y in Java?

Tags: java, random

Excuse me, if this is plain obvious, but I don't quite get it. Why doesn't the `Random` class simply have a `Random.nextInt(min, max)` or `Random.nextLong(min, max)` method? What's the deal with this cryptic and overly unintuitive way of doing things?

I've seen examples of how to get a random `int` between `1` and `100`, for example, but I can't figure out how one would do this for a `long` instead. Could somebody please illustrate this and maybe explain the need to have this done in such a confusing way...?

Comment: If you want a random num between say 50-100 you just use `50 + random.nextInt(51)`.

Comment: I'm supposed to generate a random `long` for a file size with a given limit of bytes (usually between a few `MB` and a few `GB`), so all the functions are expecting a `long`.

Comment: @user902383 : You actually cannot do `min + Random.nextLong(max-min);`, because there is no method `nextLong` accepting parameters.

Comment: This answer was also quite useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968914/how-to-generate-a-random-long-between-x-and-y-in-java/22969061?noredirect=1#comment35073731_22969061.

Comment: A Java double has only 52 bits of precision, so if the range of longs you need is larger than 2**52, you'll either have to settle for not getting all the possible values in the range, or else do the range-limiting yourself after calling nextLong() (or perhaps nextDouble() twice). How best to do that depends on your application's needs. A library function might not be ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said, you can just use the lower + random * (upper-lower+1) formula. It should be pretty obvious why that works, but if not, try working through a few examples. Also, if you have a formula to get an int between two numbers, that same formula will work with longs. What happened when you tried?

However, if you really want an out-of-the-box way to do this, Java 8 adds a method to the Random class that gives you random long values in a range: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#longs-long-long-long-

Comment: I would prefer to use the Java 8 method, but I'm limited to 1.7.0_xx. Would you mind illustrating it for numbers from `0...1000000`, maybe?

Comment: Uh, to get a random long between 0 and 1000000 (exclusive), you would just do this: Math.random()*1000000L;

Comment: No. No I do not. You could use random.nextDouble()*1000000L if you really wanted to.

Comment: Well, what you've shown above is actually for a `double`, hence my confusion. Am I missing something...?

Comment: The only thing you're missing is the cast, which I omitted to conserve comment space: long myRandomLong = (long)(random.nextDouble()*1000000L ); Or put another way, long myrandomLong = (long)(0 + random.nextDouble()*(1000000L-0+1)); would make it inclusive (0 is your lower bound, 1000000 is your upper bound inclusive), and is exactly the formula in my answer.

Comment: Right, I thought there would be another way that would give you `long`-s straight away, or was at least under that impression.

Comment: The above formula is pretty straightforward, so I don't think it really needs a place in the API. If you use it often, then put it in a utility method.

Comment: This formula will, unfortuneately, only give you 52 bits of randomness, so if your long range is greater than 2**52, you'll lost some precision.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker what is the alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Here is to generate a random long between min and max.

```
    long leftLimit = 1L;
    long rightLimit = 10L;
    long generatedLong = leftLimit + (long) (Math.random() * (rightLimit - leftLimit));
```

click [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-generate-random-long-float-integer-double) for detail.

Answer (score 0):

My Java's a little rusty, but here's an adaptation of some C code of mine that should produce a long value within the given limits, perfectly uniform, and with full 64-bit precision.

```
long longInRange(long min, long max) {
    long v, range = max - min;
    long mask = range;

    mask != mask >> 1;
    mask != mask >> 2;
    mask != mask >> 4;
    mask != mask >> 8;
    mask != mask >> 16;
    mask != mask >> 32;

    do {
        v = m & random.nextLong();
    } while (v >= range);

    return v + min;
}
```